# Linking Google's Cookie Policy on my website

Tags: firebase, cookies, policies

Good evening,
I would like to pose this question, because I am somewhat confused about Cookie Policies: I have built a website which only relies, for the backend, on Google Firebase, with Analtycs turned on; due to the fact that Firebase Analytics collects unnecessary cookies, I need to set up a Cookie Policy and a Cookie Banner, so I was wondering if I could just prompt the end user with a banner containing an information message and a link redirecting to Google's Cookie Policy, as my website does not store any other type of Cookie.

Thanks in advance for any help